# Strange Noise when I build and run application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, audio, sdl

I am rolling through a SDL 2.0 tutorial since things changed quite a bit since I learned 1.2.  I have a very simple program right now, just a window class, an application class, and a texture class.  When I debug and compile my program, I hear this like high pitched hum from my speakers.  It also occurs if I run the compiled .exe file from the debug folder.

I have no idea how to trouble shoot this.  Since it seems to be only my program, and happens on the .exe file, I doubt it is visual studio's fault.  Though I'm not really a huge programmer, it is just a hobby, so maybe it is.  It's benign to my program (thus far, as it is tiny) but it is straight up annoying. Anyone have an idea why my speakers just start spewing a noise?

Thank you in advance.

I will post my code below, but I do nothing with the SDL Audio API.

**src.cpp**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "KApp.h"


const int winW = 800;
const int winH = 600;


int main(int argc, char** argv ) {

    KApp ThisApp;

    ThisApp.Run( winW, winH);

    return 0;
}
```

**KApp.h**

```
#ifndef __KAPP_H__
#define __KAPP_H__

#include <SDL.h>
#include <vector>

#include "Window.h"
#include "KTexture.h"


class KApp {

private:

    enum States {
        INIT = 0,
        RUNNING,
        PAUSED,
        HALTED,

    };

    States GameState;
    Window* MainWindow;
    std::vector<KTexture*> Textures;

public:

    KApp();
    ~KApp();

    void Run(const int &,const int &);
    void Handle(SDL_Event* Event);
    void Update();
    void Render();

    void CleanUp();

};



#endif
```

**KApp.cpp**

```
#include "KApp.h"


KApp::KApp() {

    GameState = INIT;
    MainWindow = NULL;

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0 ) { 
        exit(0x1);
    }

    //SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE,           8);
    //SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE,         8);
    //SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE,          8);
    //SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE,         8);

    //SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE,        16);
    //SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE,       32);

    //SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCUM_RED_SIZE,     8);
    //SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCUM_GREEN_SIZE,   8);
    //SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCUM_BLUE_SIZE,    8);
    //SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCUM_ALPHA_SIZE,   8);

    //SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
    //SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 2);

    return;

}

KApp::~KApp() {

    if( MainWindow != NULL ) {
        delete MainWindow;
        MainWindow = NULL;
    }

    for( std::vector<KTexture*>::iterator it = Textures.begin(); it != Textures.end(); it++ ) {
        delete *it;
    }
    Textures.clear();

    SDL_Quit();

    return;
}

void KApp::Handle(SDL_Event* Event) {
    if(Event->type == SDL_QUIT) {
        GameState = HALTED;
    }
}

void KApp::CleanUp() {

}

void KApp::Render() {
    MainWindow->Render();
}


void KApp::Run(const int& w,const int& h) {

    MainWindow = new Window(w,h,"KApp Main Window");
    if(!MainWindow->Create()) {
        exit(1);
    }

    Textures.push_back(new KTexture("E:/Pictures/BKG.bmp"));
    Textures[0]->Optimize(MainWindow->Surface());

    MainWindow->Blit(Textures[0]->Surface());

    GameState = RUNNING;
    SDL_Event Event;

    while(GameState == RUNNING) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event)) {
            Handle(&Event);
        }

        Update();
        Render();
    }   

    CleanUp();

}

void KApp::Update() {}
```

**KWindow.h**

```
#ifndef __WINDOW_H__
#define __WINDOW_H__

#include <SDL.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>
#include <string>


class Window {

private:
    int Width;
    int Height;
    std::string Title;

    SDL_Window* WNDW;
    SDL_Surface* SFC;


public:
    Window() : Width(800),Height(600),Title("Window"),WNDW(NULL),SFC(NULL) {}
    Window(int w, int h, std::string title) : Width(w),Height(h),Title(title),WNDW(NULL),SFC(NULL) {}
    ~Window() { 
        if(WNDW != NULL) {
            SDL_DestroyWindow(WNDW);
            WNDW = NULL;
        }

    }

    bool Create() {

        if( WNDW != NULL ) {
            return true;
        }

        WNDW = SDL_CreateWindow( Title.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, Width, Height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( WNDW == NULL ) {
            return false;
        }

        SFC = SDL_GetWindowSurface( WNDW );
        SDL_FillRect ( SFC , NULL, SDL_MapRGB( SFC->format, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 ) );
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( WNDW );


        //if((Surface = SDL_SetVideoMode(Width,Height,32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER | SDL_OPENGL | SDL_RESIZABLE )) == NULL) {
        //  return false;
        //}
        /*
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        glClearDepth(1.0f);
        glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, Width, Height, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable (GL_BLEND); 
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glLoadIdentity();
        */

        return true;
    }

    void Clear() {
        SDL_FillRect ( SFC , NULL, SDL_MapRGB( SFC->format, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 ) );
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( WNDW );
    }

    void Blit(SDL_Surface* Surf) {
        SDL_BlitSurface(Surf, NULL, SFC, NULL);
    }

    void BlitScaled(SDL_Surface* Surf, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        SDL_Rect MyRectum;
        MyRectum.x = x;
        MyRectum.y = y;
        MyRectum.w = w;
        MyRectum.h = h;
        SDL_BlitScaled(Surf, NULL, SFC, &MyRectum);
    }

    void Render() {
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( WNDW );
    }

    SDL_Surface* Surface() {
        return SFC;
    }

};

#endif
```

**KTexture.h**

```
#ifndef __KTEXTURE_H__
#define __KTEXTURE_H__

#include <SDL.h>
#include <string>

class KTexture {

private:
    SDL_Surface* Texture;

public:

    KTexture() : Texture(NULL) {}
    KTexture( std::string path ) : Texture(NULL) {
        Load(path);
    }

    ~KTexture() {
        if( Texture != NULL ) {
            SDL_FreeSurface(Texture);
            Texture = NULL;
        }
    }

    bool Load( std::string path ) {

        Texture = SDL_LoadBMP( path.c_str() );
        if(Texture == NULL) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    void Render() {
        Render(0,0);
    }

    void Render(int x, int y) {


    }

    SDL_Surface* Surface() {
        return Texture;
    }

    bool Optimize(SDL_Surface* For) {
        SDL_Surface* nsurf = SDL_ConvertSurface( Texture, For->format, NULL);
        if( nsurf == NULL) {
            return false;
        }

        SDL_FreeSurface(Texture);
        Texture = nsurf;

        return true;

    }

};


#endif
```

**EDIT**  Fixed.  Added this to the KApp::Run() function

```
Uint32 Time = SDL_GetTicks();

GameState = RUNNING;
SDL_Event Event;

while(GameState == RUNNING) {
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event)) {
        Handle(&Event);
    }

    Update();
    if( SDL_GetTicks() > Time + 300) {
        Render();
        Time = SDL_GetTicks();
    }
    else
    {
        SDL_Delay(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the CPU load while the program is running?

Comment: I did, it was like 30%, but the frame rate restriction fixed the noise.
Adding a sleep in there fixed the CPU usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen this happen when you have an app that runs at a really high frame rate. The high pitched sound usually comes from the graphics card.

Try enabling vsync or limiting the framerate of your application in your code.